# Error installing java package in Python

Tags: python, java-io

I need to use for a project the **java.io** package in a **Python** environment, but I am encountering this error while trying to install it:

```
Collecting java

Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement java (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for java
```

Image of the error:   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEmjk.jpg)

Comment: I use python 3X

Comment: Do you have java installed? If so what version? Are you sure that the package name is just `java`?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/image/kgdsxp6ob/ this is a picture of my java in my PC.  the tutorial showed that I have to import java.io. this is also the picture of tutorial https://postimg.cc/image/qhbhuzj2j/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a tutorial for Jython not the standard Python (which is technically cpython).

I found the tutorial here:

https://keggscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonscripting.html

It looks like you skipped over this part:

"Next we show a sample to batch-import kgml files from Python script. To use Python from Cytoscape3, you need to download jython-standalone from here , and move the jython-standalone like this."

Jython is an alternative implementation of Python that runs on the Java virtual machine. Being java-based, it lets you import the standard Java libraries.

This code will simply not work in standard Python 3.

You need to learn to pay attention to details if you want to be a successful programmer.

Comment: thank for your response and kind advice, could you please help me with my main question that  whether it is possible to integrate my python script to this tutorial or not? I've written my codes now I want to meld these two together.

Comment: You need to install Jython. That is the only way